# Configuring Keycloak through its REST API with cUrl

Tags: rest, keycloak, openid-connect, keycloak-rest-api

I need to configure Keycloak to get a JWT token as in [this blog post](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/01/29/api-login-and-jwt-token-generation-using-keycloak/), but I have to do it with cUrl.  They create a client and then update it setting `access type` to `confidential`, `Direct Grant Flow` to `direct grant`, and `Browser Flow` to `browser`.  The `PUT` request from the web UI that does this has some `uuids` that they seem to have pulled out of nowhere.  Here is the relevant part of the payload:

```
"authenticationFlowBindingOverrides":{"browser":"6d77c4c7-15cf-4474-9b9f-7439dbc83b83","direct_grant":"5cb10cdb-9902-4f7f-b9da-68f887c49a75"}
```

The docs for the [ClientRepresentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/index.html#_clientrepresentation) are no help.  They show all fields are optional, which doesn't make sense, and the `authenticationFlowBindingOverrides` is a Map, but the [link in their docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/index.html#_map) for the Map is dead.

Does anyone know where they get the uuids for browser and direct_grant from?

There is also nothing in the PUT payload that sets the `Access Type` to `confidential`.

If anyone has a cUrl implementation of the UI steps in the [blog post](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/01/29/api-login-and-jwt-token-generation-using-keycloak/) that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The PUT request from the web UI that does this has some uuids that
> they seem to pull out of nowhere.

Those uuids are generated by keycloak to get them you need to call the endpoint:

```
GET KEYCLOAK_HOST/auth/admin/realms/<YOUR_REALM>/authentication/flows
```

From the `JSON` response you need to parser it and get the field `id` of both the `alias: "browser"` and the alias: `"direct grant"`.

After that call the endpoint:

```
PUT KEYCLOAK_HOST/auth/admin/realms/<YOUR_REALM>/clients/<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>
```

with the following payload:

```
'{"publicClient":false,"clientAuthenticatorType":"client-secret","authenticationFlowBindingOverrides":{"direct_grant":"<DIRECT_GRANT_ID>","browser":"<BROWSER_ID>"}}'
```

> There is also nothing in the PUT payload that sets the Access Type to
> confidential.

You need to set the field `publicClient` to `false`.